# Save Images from a webpage using Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, save, feed

I wrote a little javascript application with jquery which fetches a rss feed via the Google Feed API and displays it as a grid of images.

The code then looks like :

```
<ul>
...
<li><a class="entry" href="LINK_TO_BIG_IMAGE" title="TITLE_OF_ENTRY"><img class="entry-img" src="THUMB_IMG" alt="" /></a></li>
...
</ul>
```

What I want to do is to be able to save the images all at once in a folder on the server. For now I'd be happy if it does it on page load. Is it possible via Javascript ? Do you have some direction to point me to ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to save images in a folder *on the server* using JavaScript that runs *on the client*? Am I correct? If so, you can't do this directly, you'll have to send an HTTP request to the server (either using a form or an XMLHttpRequest) that starts a script that does what you want.

Comment: So would a submit button do a trick ? Like, I could easily get all the images paths via javascript, then push them into a textarea, click on the submit button, which would then fire a script server-side right ? I guess there are better ways of course but I'm trying to do this with my own skills and I'm a beginner.

Comment: You could grab the paths and put them in a hidden field and submit the paths to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment about submitting the paths to a php script on the server would work ( I wouldn't recommend doing it that way but it works).

Your php could then download the images like so (untested and you'd need to parse the filename from the $url when you go to save the file).

```
<?php

$image_urls = isset($_POST['image_urls']) ? $_POST['image_urls'] : null;//assume it's an array of urls

if (!count($image_urls))//check that our array actually contains 1 or more urls
{
  die('no urls provided');
}

$image_folder_path = '/home/somefolder/';

foreach ($image_paths as $index => $url)
{
  $file_name = $image_folder_path . $index . '.jpg';//you will need to parse the url for the file name and extension for this to be accurate

  $image = file_get_contents($url);//if fopen wrappers is enabled you can do this otherwise use something like cUrl to fetch the file
  file_put_contents($file_name, $image);
}

?>
```